# IBM MQ 8.0.0.x C++ Includes

Tags: c++, ibm-mq

I have Websphere MQ client, MQ explorer and MQ samples (Ver 8.0.0.4) installed in my Redhat Linux 7.5 development box. I am trying to run the sample C/C++ programs that came with the installation. However I am unable to find the include files needed to run the examples, particularly imqi.hpp. I have tried, I can't find IBM documentation about this. Where to find this? What component or what am I missing?

Edit:

MQSeriesRuntime-8.0.0-4.x86_64

MQSeriesJRE-8.0.0-4.x86_64

MQSeriesExplorer-8.0.0-4.x86_64

MQSeriesJava-8.0.0-4.x86_64

MQSeriesSamples-8.0.0-4.x86_64

MQSeriesClient-8.0.0-4.x86_64

Comment: Can you provide the output from `rpm -qa | grep -i MQSeries`, please edit and add it to your question.

Comment: Yes. I have added that.

Comment: See mark's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Header files are in the MQSeriesSDK rpm component which you don't mention as having installed

Comment: That was it. Thanks!